# How to split date and time from a datetime string?

Tags: java, android, datetime, split

I have a string like
`8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM`. I want to split that string into separate variables like

```
date = 8/29/2011
time = 11:16:12 AM
```

Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: When I get this kind a string I was subtract it and create a Date object. But maybe there is easier method.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**(Edit: See [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58654203/642706) below for a more modern (Java 8) approach for the first version)**

One way to do is parse it to a date object and reformat it again:

```
    try {
        DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        Date d = f.parse("8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM");
        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        DateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        System.out.println("Date: " + date.format(d));
        System.out.println("Time: " + time.format(d));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you just want to slice it into date-time pieces, just use split to get pieces

```
    String date = "8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM";
    String[] parts = date.split(" ");
    System.out.println("Date: " + parts[0]);
    System.out.println("Time: " + parts[1] + " " + parts[2]);
```

or

```
    String date = "8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM";
    System.out.println("Date: " + date.substring(0, date.indexOf(' ')));
    System.out.println("Time: " + date.substring(date.indexOf(' ') + 1));
```

Comment: FYI, the date-time classes seen here are now obsolete, supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. For the modern solution, see the [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58654203/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque sure, I will try to update it. Another thing is for this particular problem -if strict validation is not required-, doing it with just splitting the string or getting the substring is much faster.

Answer (score 3):

Why not to use DateFormat?

Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

```
String str = "8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM";

String fmt = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(fmt);

Date dt = df.parse(str);

DateFormat tdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
DateFormat dfmt  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");


String timeOnly = tdf.format(dt);
String dateOnly = dfmt.format(dt);
```

It gives more work/code but it's the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

### java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and ThreeTenABP

It’s time someone provides the modern answer to this question. I do here.

I am not at complete ease with your requirements, though. For the vast majority of purposes and situations you should not keep your date nor your time of day in a string. You should use proper date-time objects. So as I see it, this is what you should want to do:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2011, Month.AUGUST, 29, 11, 16, 12);
    LocalDate date = dateTime.toLocalDate();
    LocalTime time = dateTime.toLocalTime();
    System.out.println("date = " + date);
    System.out.println("time = " + time);
```

Output is:

> ```
> date = 2011-08-29
> time = 11:16:12
> ```

Assuming that `8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM` has been entered as user input you need to parse it into a `LocalDateTime` that you can keep in your program. This goes like this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u h:m:s a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String userInput = "8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(userInput, formatter);
    System.out.println("dateTime = " + dateTime);
```

> ```
> dateTime = 2011-08-29T11:16:12
> ```

Going the other way, to output to the user: If your separate date and time strings are for output only, we don’t need to separate date and time before formatting into those strings. We can format the `LocalDateTime` directly.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u");
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String dateString = dateTime.format(dateFormatter);
    String timeString = dateTime.format(timeFormatter);
    System.out.println("dateString = " + dateString);
    System.out.println("timeString = " + timeString);
```

> ```
> dateString = 8/29/2011
> timeString = 11:16:12 AM
> ```

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String main = "8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM";
        String[] tmp;
        String date, time;

        tmp = main.split(" ");

        // [0] = 8/29/2011
        // [1] = 11:16:12
        // [2] = AM

        date = tmp[0].toString(); // 8/29/2011
        time = tmp[1].toString() + " " + tmp[2].toString(); // 11:16:12 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `split` function in Java:

```
String my_string="8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM"
String [] my_date_time = null;
my_date_time = my_string.split(" ");
String Date_str=my_date_time[0];
String Time_str=my_date_time[1]+" "+my_date_time[2];
```

You get variable Strings like this `Date_str="8/29/2011"` and `Time_str="11:16:12 AM"`

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM"
String date = str.subString(0, str.indexOf(' '));
String time  = str.subString(str.indexOf(' ')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by splitting your string into two substrings, as follows

```
String main = "8/29/2011 11:16:12 AM";
String s[] = main.split(" ",2);
String date = s[0];
String time = s[1];
```

**NOTE**: The split method will split the string into two parts as mentioned in the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
mDate = new Date();
DateFormat timeFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance();
DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance();
timeFormat.format(mDate); // formats to: 4:53:03 AM
dateFormat.format(mDate); // formats to: Oct 16, 2014
```

Comment: Please explain your answers instead of just posting "try this" type of solutions.