# Get current time in milliseconds in Java (just time, not date as well)

Tags: java, time

I want to get the current time in milliseconds. I'm using System.currentTimeMillis() but this returns the date as well as the time. I simply want "15:03" in milliseconds, not the date too.

Note that I want an integer and not a formatted string. If it was 08:30, this is the equivalent to 30600 seconds, which is in turn equivalent to 30600000 milliseconds. This is the value I want

Comment: In which timezone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time and Date from datetime stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886751/how-to-get-time-and-date-from-datetime-stamp)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn GMT

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns **the difference** between now and January 1, 1970, what are your milliseconds supposed to be?

Comment: @Vidhi unfortunately that is dealing with formatted strings, I want an integer, the value stored as milliseconds

Comment: @AndrewTobilko the milliseconds should just be the current time that you see on your clock. I.e. 08:30 would be 30600000 milliseconds

Comment: You can get rid of the date part by taking the modulo with the number of millis seconds in a one day,       System.currentTimeMillisd() % 86400000L

Comment: @Yash Morar David's comment above is the best answer

Comment: @DavidZimmerman You should write your comment as an answer

Comment: @DavidZimmerman Much easier to use the *java.time* class, and more obvious with self-documenting code.

Comment: Dear down-voters, please leave a criticism along with your vote. If you think this is a duplicate, find the original. I tried but could not find any other. So I am up-voting here.

Comment: @DavidZimmerman Doing the math yourself is the way to code that is harder to read. Avoid that. Use the the standard classes for well-tested functionality and self-explanatory code in your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between( todayStart , now ).toMillis()
```

## Details

Get the current moment in the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “Africa/Tunis” ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Get the first moment of the day. Do not assume this is 00:00:00. Let java.time determine.

```
ZonedDateTime todayStart = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Represent the delta between them, the span of time unattached to the timeline, as a `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( todayStart , now ) ;
```

A `Duration` has a resolution of nanoseconds. That is finer than the milliseconds you desire. A convenience method will ignore any microseconds or nanoseconds for you.

```
long millisSinceStartOfToday = d.toMillis() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class:

```
long millis = LocalTime.now().toNanoOfDay() / 1_000_000;
```

Basil Bourque correctly points out that it isn’t always this simple:  a Daylight Saving Time change (such as will occur in most of the US this Sunday) can mean that, for example, there may not be eight hours between midnight and 8 AM.

You can account for this by using a ZonedDateTime, which accounts for all calendar information, including DST changeovers:

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime start = now.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
long millis = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(start, now);
```

Comment: Not a complete Answer without explaining time zone.

Comment: Does not account for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Comment: @BasilBourque Timezone and DST are irrelevant.  Local time is local time regardless of its offset from GMT.

Comment: Nope. Very much relevant. For example, in some places Daylight Saving Time (DST) cutover takes place at first moment of the day. So at the stroke of midnight, the clock jumps to 1 AM. The hour between 00:00 and 01:00 never existed. Your code would incorrectly report *two* hours of milliseconds having elapsed for a `LocalTime` of 2 AM when in fact only *one* hour of milliseconds elapsed.

Comment: @BasilBourque Right you are.  Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in the millis since midnight in the GMT timezone, the easiest approach is probably:

```
int millis = LocalTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY);
```

Comment: I like the `.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY)` very much, it’s so clear to read the intention. Other date-time classes can be used instead of `OffsetTime` including `LocalTime`.