# Kotlin check existing date in string

Tags: java, android, kotlin

this is my string 
val fulldate = "10/30/2019 6:10:52 AM"
how I can I get separate this string in to date and time.
val date = "10/30/2019"
val time = "6:10:52 AM"

Comment: can you try to work with string manipulation and/or regex for this? If the fulldate is in a constant format, you should be able to do it without much hassle, just try to work with edge cases, I guess. Try do some code by yourself! And add the code here if you get stuck.

Comment: a bit hint: first split the string by the spaces, then you got 3 variable, then combine the last two as one variable, you'll get there, or you can just split it by the first space only.

Comment: I took this occasion for writing [a new answer to one of the original questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58654203/5772882). I think it matches very well with yur requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String#split`, with the second limit parameter to split only on the first space separating the date and time components:

```
String fulldate = "10/30/2019 6:10:52 AM";
System.out.println("date: " + fulldate.split(" ", 2)[0]);
System.out.println("time: " + fulldate.split(" ", 2)[1]);
```

This prints:

```
date: 10/30/2019
time: 6:10:52 AM
```